# C# : List<string> get in between records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to **c#**. I have a List of 100 records. I want to take between 20 to 30 index records.

Is there any easy way of getting this **without for loop** ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, You can use .Skip() and .Take() methods.

Try this code:

```
Records = Records.Skip(20).Take(10).ToList();
```

This will skip first 20 records and takes next 10 record.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ `Skip` and `Take` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
int skip = 20;
int take=10;
List<string> filteredList = records.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

You can also Use GetRange Method of Linq.

```
List<Record> record = Records.GetRange(20,10);
```

Just to make sure that it fits your scenario It does shallow copy only.